# Google Sheets web app to run script as owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-sheets-api

Hi have a simple script that sends an email from a spreadsheet I need to allow the other users of the sheet to call the script but I want the script to be ran as me (the owner) so that the email is sent from my account. I've looked at some similar questions and answers but nothing seems to work.

I've got a button on my sheet calling the doGet function with the following code.

```
function doGet(e){

  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/a/----.org/macros/s/AKfycbxT------------------------------FK5GbrkI/exec').getResponseCode();

}
```

If I go to the URL from a browser tab script runs fine but I can't get it to work from clicking the button on my spreadsheet

Comment: any error while calling this from spreadsheet?

Comment: before calling this function from button click call it manually from dropdown

Comment: Nope, no errors, just nothing happens. Call it from a dropdown? Do you mean a custom menu? If I try to add a .ui then I get an error saying that .ui can't be called in this instance.

Comment: What @NitinDhomse is trying to say is, execute the email sending function manually from the `Code.gs`.

Comment: @JamesDonnellan is there any particular reason to run the script from your account?

Comment: @JamesDonnellan Post your code here, for adding menu to spreadsheet

Comment: Manually calling the code is not an option as other users will be running the script, not me. It needs to be sent from my account because the email needs to come from one of my aliases and 2/3 different people who will be running the script. There is no menu, just a drawing set to call the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) webapp to handle the emailing. When the user calls the script, a [web request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) is issued from the GAS bound script of the spreadsheet to the published [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), and in the webapp you can email from your own account (i.e., "Execute the app as: Me"). You can pass arguments as well, for example the email recipient and text could be sent as parameters. Here is a picture for clarity:

[image]

Comment: Yes, funny I have looked at all of those web pages before but it never occurred to me to do it in this way!

Comment: Thank you James! Feel free to ask any follow-up questions; I had to implement things like these plenty of times in GAS. Also, depending on how you are deploying the Google Sheet, you may also find it helpful to have a shared secret key saved in your spreadsheet and then verify it using the backend webapp script, or to perhaps verify that the recipient of the email is, in fact, also an editor of your Google Sheet. Good luck! :)