# How to allow a user to execute a google script that changes another spreadsheet the user doesn't have the access to

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building an accounting system for a small business using Google Sheets. I have different spreadsheets:

- 1 with the list of all the students attending courses
- 1 used by the secretary to manage the invoicing
- 1 for the "boss" where he can see his business balance.

I wrote many functions with Google script to automatically update all the others spreadsheet when some changes are made.

Here is the problem, as you can imagine I can't grant the access to the balance sheet to all the users. Is there a way to allow every user to run a script that makes changes to a spreadsheet they don't have the access to?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using a web app to allow users call your script as you.

1. Create your script
2. Create and publish a web app which calls your script / function
3. crate another script / function that the end user can run to call your web app URL

[Google Sheets web app to run script as owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397968/google-sheets-web-app-to-run-script-as-owner)